# Discretize a continuous time Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am aware of the existence of the following questions:
[How to discretely stochastically simulate a continuous-time Markov chain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613607/how-to-discretely-stochastically-simulate-a-continuous-time-markov-chain)
[Recipe to discretize a continuous- time markov process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458424/recipe-to-discretize-a-continuous-time-markov-process)

I tried to understand them, but frankly, I couldn't.

Like in discreet time Markov chain, I want to find the probability of being in state $j$ at interval $k$ (discretized). I know of the rate matrix and initial probability distribution. How would I do that?

References will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reference perfectly answers my question:

DOYTCHINOV, BOGDAN, and RACHEL IRBY. "TIME DISCRETIZATION OF MARKOV CHAINS." Pi Mu Epsilon Journal 13, no. 2 (2010): 69-82. http://www.jstor.org/stable/24340803.